# Array not sorting as expected

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have following array

```
temp =  [1230, 900, 1000, 2130, 2400]
```

and used `temp.sort()` to sort it by value and when see it using console.log its gives following

```
[1000, 1230, 2130, 2400, 900]
```

this supposed to be done like

```
[900, 1000, 1230, 2130, 2400]
```

is there anything wrong or need to use some other method ?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): "If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order."

Answer (score 1):

You should use `compareFunction` of [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If `compareFunction` is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For example, In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order.

```js
var temp = [1230, 900, 1000, 2130, 2400];
temp.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
})

snippet.log(temp)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: As an explanation: the sort function sorts by Unicode code points by default, and `9` comes after `2` in that case.

Comment: From the duplicate: _The compare function should return -1, 0 or +1. a>b will only return true or false_